# Fetch particular number of events from eventStore

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, ekeventstore

We know that we can fetch events from EventStore using predicate. It contains start date and end date. Using this all the events that belong in this time period are fetched.

However I am searching for something which will allow me to fetch only particular number of events from Event Store - e.g : Fetch first 100 events from event store. Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Use the enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate:withBlock: method. Increment a counter every time executing the block and when a limit is reached, change the value pointed to by stop to YES. Every time executing the block also add the event to a mutable collection.